# view design issue: how can I make scroll view's child view fill screen?

Tags: android, view

stackoverflow. 
I'm making a android input form view now, and have some issues in using scroll view.

First, please see my drawing. 
design blueprint

[image]

I want to put some editTexts in views vertical, and put a submit button bottom of screen. But scrollView's child component's layout_height should be wrap_content, not match parent. So my submit button sets just below of last edit text. It would be easy if I could put some margin between last editText and button, but I can't. if I do that, I think layouts makes some problem in different device size.

This is my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.ResendPwActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/title_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/prev_btn"
                android:layout_width="9dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/prev"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/change_pw_string"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="-25dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/change_password"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/title_layout"
            android:background="#dddddd" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_pw_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/current_pw_string"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/current_pw_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/current_pw_label"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/email_password_edittext_line_color_selector"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password_hint"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/new_pw_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/current_pw_input"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/new_pw_string"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/new_pw_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/new_pw_label"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/email_password_edittext_line_color_selector"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password_hint"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/validate_pw_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/new_pw_input"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/validate_new_pw_string"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/validate_pw_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/validate_pw_label"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/email_password_edittext_line_color_selector"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password_hint"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/validate_pw_input" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/update_profile_btn_selector"
            android:text="@string/update_change"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.ResendPwActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/title_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/prev_btn"
                    android:layout_width="9dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/prev"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/change_pw_string"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="-25dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/change_password"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/title_layout"
                android:background="#dddddd" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/current_pw_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/line"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="@string/current_pw_string"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="13sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/current_pw_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/current_pw_label"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/email_password_edittext_line_color_selector"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/new_pw_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/current_pw_input"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="@string/new_pw_string"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/new_pw_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/new_pw_label"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/email_password_edittext_line_color_selector"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/validate_pw_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/new_pw_input"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="@string/validate_new_pw_string"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="13sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/validate_pw_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/validate_pw_label"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/email_password_edittext_line_color_selector"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/validate_pw_input" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/update_profile_btn_selector"
                android:text="@string/update_change"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: This is what I wanted! Did you just add android:fillViewport="true" right?? thank you for your help. You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

your button should be at the bottom of screen for better responsive UI
and scrollview must only one child so you can not add button and relativelayout in scrollview at a time

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.ResendPwActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/submit_btn"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/title_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/prev_btn"
                    android:layout_width="9dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/prev"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/change_pw_string"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="-25dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/change_password"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/title_layout"
                android:background="#dddddd" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/current_pw_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/line"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="@string/current_pw_string"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="13sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/current_pw_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/current_pw_label"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/email_password_edittext_line_color_selector"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/new_pw_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/current_pw_input"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="@string/new_pw_string"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/new_pw_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/new_pw_label"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/email_password_edittext_line_color_selector"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/validate_pw_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/new_pw_input"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="@string/validate_new_pw_string"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="13sp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/validate_pw_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/validate_pw_label"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/email_password_edittext_line_color_selector"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
            <!--for responsive layout Button should be out side of scroll -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/update_profile_btn_selector"
        android:text="@string/update_change"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```